# TFS 2010 permissions to folders and files

Tags: tfs, permissions

Hear All,

Could you help me solve following task. There is some folder in tfs source control. For instance, "Configs". There is standard "Contributors" user group. I want to allow make check-ins to some part of "Contributors" group. I'm tried to create new group "Leads", where I added people who can made check-ins. Than I deny check-ins to "contributors", and "allow" for "leads", by default "leads" allow do all.

But after this people who in the both groups, can't do check-ins.

Please advise me, how I should correctly organize user groups grand check-ins permissions for certain group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In TFS deny always wins. The easiest way to solve this without removing the leads from the contributors group is to uncheck allow for contibutors, do not use deny. This will stop contibutors from being able to access the folder.

In this scenario Contibutors will not be allowed to access the folder but leads will so users can continue to be members of both groups.

You may also have to stop inheritance.