# Users are being re-added to "Build Services" group

Tags: tfs

I am having permissions issues with my team.  Some team members keep losing access to certain folders in TFS.  They are in the "Contributors" group which has access to these folders.  When they lose access, I discover they are in the "Build Services" group which does not have access.  I remove them from "Build Services", but after a while they keep getting re-added and lose permissions again.

Anyone have any ideas?

***Edit:  I discovered that the "Contributors" group is a member of "Build Services" group.  I would imagine this would cause weird permissions conflicts, correct?***

Comment: You should remove users from the build services group. This group is for service accounts only and should not be used for Humans. (in fact it's a legacy group from TFS 2005 / 2008, if you create a new team project in TFS 2010 you won't have a build services group as Team Build has changed significantly in TFS 2010)

Comment: In addition to the comment above, the permissions problem is probably related to the fact that Deny always wins in TFS permissions see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7843007/568475) for more detail

Comment: Thanks for the responses, got the wheels turning about "Build Services" group and I think I have it resolved now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the "Contributors" group is a member of "Build Services" group.  This was causing permissions conflicts (And users being listed as belonging to "Build Services" using TFSecurity.exe and not in the UI.

I removed the "Contributors" group from the "Build Services" group and that seemed to fix everyone's problems.  Not sure how that happened.  Too many spoons in the pot perhaps.